# How to limit the request parameters in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm stuck with web services in Azure ML :/

I am setting up a web service with Azure Machine Learning to estimate a car price based on 5 attributes out of 150 in my database. It works fine in the way that if I provide in the test endpoint 5 attributes out of the 150 it requires, it gives me a valid answer. As you can see below "Scored Label : 10185....".

My question is the following : how do you get the web service to only require 4 input ? The ones I want are in the output (gearingType,MakeTxt,mileage,modelTxt). Price, is off course what I try to guess.

Thanks for any help!
Regards,
Alexandre

[image: unexpected endpoint fields in input (150 vs 4) and output (6 vs 1)]

Here is what my experience looks like, as you can see I used "Select Columns in Dataset" to select my 4 input + 1 output [image: here is what it looks like in AzureML]

[image: and here are the columns I selected]

[image: unexpected endpoint fields in input (150 vs 4) and output (6 vs 1)]

Comment: Only thing I can think is to save the new dataset with only the columns you need and use that as the starting dataset in the experiment instead of the original one.

Comment: Hi Jon, Unfortunately it's an Azure Table and I would like to keep it intact in order to improve the model overtime without losing the data I collect today.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not doing any pre-processing on your price column, then you need to remove the price from your Import Data before joining with the Web Service Input, in your predictive experiment.

This is because ML Studio uses the structure from your training dataset to determine the structure of the Web Service Input (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/walkthrough-5-publish-web-service#convert-the-training-experiment-to-a-predictive-experiment) for more info).

Here's a light sample of how it could look (note that this particular sample was doing some light pre-processing on the price column, which I had to remove in order for it to work).

[image: filtering price from the web service input]

Comment: Hi Vlad! Thanks for your help, unfortunately when I add a "Select Columns in Data" between my "Import Data" and "Apply transformation", it throws me an error,  saying it requires the fields I just deleted.  I'm not doing any kind of preprocessing on price....

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're applying some other operation to all columns (or at least to a subset including price)?In my case (sample 5) there's a Clean Missing Data module that was applied to all columns, and Apply Transformation gave me the same error, until I manually excluded "income" and then it worked.